# Can two .class files stored under arbitrarily different paths belong to the same package?

Tags: java

Two .java files `A.java` and `B.java` both have this line:

```
package mypackage
```

If I would like `A.class` and `B.class` both belong to the same package `mypackage`,
do I need to follow some rules to store `A.class` and `B.class`?

Can I store `A.class` as `/pathnametoA/A.class` and `B.class` is stored under `/pathnametoB/B.class`, where `pathnametoA` and `pathnametoB` are arbitrary pathnames?

For example, someone wrote `B.java` as a Junit test file to test `A.java`, and they both belong to the same package `mypackage`. I thought `A.class` and `B.class` would be stored under the same directory `mypackage`, but `A.class` is actually stored under `/commondpath/bin/mypackage` and `B.class` under `/commonpath/test/mypackage`. Can `A.class` and `B.class` belong to the same package `mypackage`?

Note that I use `javac` and `java` in command line in Ubuntu.

Thanks.

---

Update:

Is a package in Java defined as all the .class files under a directory?

So there is a one-to-one correspondence between packages and pathnames of directories?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: I have tried the example. It works but I don't understand what rules I need to follow.

Comment: You need to write `package commondpath.bin.mypackage` for `A` and `common path.test.mypackage` for `B`, but both of them are not under the same package, both `mypackage` are different since they belong to different paths

Comment: Thanks. Is a package in Java defined as all the .class files under a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Two .java files `A.java` and `B.java` both have this line:

```
package mypackage
```

> If I would like `A.class` and `B.class` both belong to the same package `mypackage`,

They already do. You said so in the source file.

> do I need to follow some rules to store `A.class` and `B.class`?

You need to store them both in a directory called `mypackage`.

> Can I store `A.class` as `/pathnametoA/A.class` and `B.class` is stored under `/pathnametoB/B.class`, where `pathnametoA` and `pathnametoB` are arbitrary pathnames?

Not unless you satisfy the condition mentioned above. They won't be found. You will get `ClassNotFoundException`.

> For example, someone wrote `B.java` as a Junit test file to test `A.java`, and they both belong to the same package `mypackage`. I thought `A.class` and `B.class` would be stored under the same directory `mypackage`, but `A.class` is actually stored under `/commondpath/bin/mypackage` and `B.class` under `/commonpath/test/mypackage`. Can `A.class` and `B.class` belong to the same package `mypackage`?

Yes, if both `commonpath/bin` and `commonpath/test` are mentioned in the CLASSPATH.

> Is a package in Java defined as all the .class files under a directory?

No, it is defined  as all the classes that have the same `package` statement.

> So there is a one-to-one correspondence between packages and pathnames of directories?

No, as per your example.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM loads classes using a Class Loader. The default class loaders use a `CLASSPATH` and the full name of the class to find the `.class` file.

In your case, if `CLASSPATH` references both `/commondpath/bin` and `/commonpath/test`, it will look in those two folders for the files `mypackage/A.class` and `mypackage/B.class`.

The `CLASSPATH` identifies the root folders of the *package hierarchy*. You cannot store `A.class` in a folder named `pathnametoA`.

Well, not unless you install your own Class Loaders for lookup up the `.class` files using a different scheme, and that is *really* not a good idea.

See section "[Class Path and Package Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHBDEEB)" of chapter 2 "Setting the Class Path document" of the "Java Platform, Standard Edition Tools Reference".

Comment: Thanks. The link you gave belongs to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/toc.html. Is the document specific to Windows? I am using Ubuntu? Does the document have a pdf file  to download?

Comment: @Ben: the Unix version is under https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/toc.html -- but although the syntax of shell commands differs from CMD commands, the way Java ClassLoader searches is the same for all platforms. In short, they can be under different paths _ending with the package name(s)_ but _not arbitrarily_ different paths.